# How to obtain a certain data from an external sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'd like to get data from an external database the fastest way. My problem is that I can make the query and get all the data then using JSON I am able to obtain what I need. But I am curious if there is a faster solution, so I go over all the data in the php, then find the appropriate data I need and returning ONLY it to the JSON instead of the whole query. The first solution might be slow when I need hunderds of records out of one million.

This would be the .php code looking for the username in case of an ID. How can I give that ID to the .php script?

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USERNAME FROM APPUSERS WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt -> execute(array($id));
        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $userdata[] = $row;
        }
    $response = '1';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response = '0';
}

print(json_encode($userdata));
```

If I remove the WHERE part of the sql code I can get all records in the table with the following code:

```
try{
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mywebpage.com/query.php");
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        Bresult=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
```

Then from this Bresult variable I get retrieve the appropriate record e.g.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(ViewPagerActivity.Bresult);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
  if (jsonObject.getString("ID").equals("12345") {
      String user = jsonObject.getString("USERNAME");
  }
}
```

So I go through all the records then retrieve the username I need.
However, I think this can be made faster if I can retrieve only the username I need and not all the records. The question is, how I can do it?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: it'd be up to the PHP code to accept a list of parameters it can build into a `where` clause in the database query. how you go about that is up to you.

Comment: I rephrased the question. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @JaniBela sorry I don't understand your question. In general try to fetch with sql so less data rows as possible. Than it is better to let the server do the hole network comunication and just return the result via http to your mobile client. The connection of your server is proberbly 100x faster than the waek mobile connection.